# Eigenvalue and Eigenvector of a squared matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given that I have eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$ and eigenvectors $v_{1},\dots,v_{n}$ for matrix $A$.

What would happen if I calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the squared matrix $A^2$?

Are they the squares of the previous values? Or are they totally unrelated?

I couldn't find this property online.

Comment: Do you make the assumption that, in your case, there are as many distinct eigenvalues as the size of your matrix ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look

$$Av_i=\lambda_i v_i\Rightarrow A^2v_i=A(Av_i)=\lambda_iAv_i=\lambda_i^2v_i$$
so what you can conclude?

Comment: So, the eigenvalues are squared and the eigenvectors are the same?

Comment: @KuramaYoko yes correct and you can generalize this for $A^p$.

Comment: But couldn't there be more? For example, if $A$ is a 180 degree rotation around the z-axis in 3D, then only the z-aligned vectors are eigenvectors. But $A^2$ is the identity, so all vectors are its eigenvectors. Therefore $A^2$ has eigenvectors that $A$ doesn't have.